# Why my splash screen don't go full screen?

Tags: html, css, angular, splash-screen

I have an Angular 6 application that has a splash screen, I want the splash screen go full height but I don't know what is wrong. This is the image today :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4x2C.jpg

```
    body,
    html {
      height: 100%;
    }

    .m-splash-screen {
      background-color: #3c1977;
      position: absolute;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 99999;
    }
  </style>
```

this is my CSS what i must do?

Comment: fixed intead of absolute

Comment: Actually it would depend on what/who is the parent of `.m-splash-screen` element. Also you may apply `top:0; left:0;` to `.m-splash-screen`.

Answer (score 0):

Use position fixed, absolute will take 100% of height initially, but when you scroll it will not cover the entire screen.